# What is Communications error: OS_xpc_error in Xcode 7.2?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using SDWebImage to download image async from server.

Some images on server are of size( 1772x1476 pixels).

I'm showing these images on UICollectionView. I'm getting memory warning and app crashes after several time I am scrolling.

Some times it happens when images downloaded first time and some time when I scroll the collection view up and down .

In my console I am getting this below message:

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x3b3c2614> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3b3c286c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

Nearly some times 600 images are coming from server.

What is the cause? Can anyone guide me please.

I am getting a warning on my x code like below image:
[image]

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33476554/1699210)