# What is Communications error: OS_xpc_error in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using SDWebImage to download image async from server.Some images on server are of size( 1772x1476 pixels.)I'm showing these images on UICollectionView. I'm getting memory warning and app crashes after several time i am scrolling.Some times it happens when images downloaded first time and some time when i scroll the collection view up and down
in my console i am getting this  below this messages some times i am getting first message and some times second

```
1)Received memory warning.

2)Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x3b3c2614> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3b3c286c> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
```

Nearly some times 600 images are coming from server
what is the cause can any one guide me please
i am getting warning on my x code like below image

[image]

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795166/what-is-communications-error-os-xpc-error-in-xcode-6

Comment: yes seen but i am not understand there answer because i am very new for ios

Comment: in which device are you tried

Comment: i tried in 4s and in my ipad

Comment: good in here try once in iphone 6 or above

Comment: won't we face this problem in iphone 6 or above?

Comment: ya got it , in here your device memory is low at the same time ur app memory is increased that the reason it will crash your app, if you have a doubt just enable the instrument and check ,you get where it is occur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108772/discussion-between-krish-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Communications error: <OS\_xpc\_error:' while recording video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476554/communications-error-os-xpc-error-while-recording-video)

Comment: Hi @Dipen Panchasara

Comment: Hi i have 9.2.1 updated software version in my device